# SignalR hub connection StateChanged not working client

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, signalr

Working with .net Core and have setup everything using this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio.

I wanted to be able to use lifetime events based on this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

However I get:

> connection.stateChanged or connection.disconnected is not a function

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
connection.start().then(function () {
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

connection.stateChanged(function () {
    console.log('in');
});
```

I would like to detect "**disconnected**" even on the client.

Comment: stateChanged is deprecated. It's not part of SignalR Core. So use `connection.onclose(function(){ .. });` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MS Doc on [`HubConnectionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnectionstate?view=aspnetcore-2.2) , there are only 2 states:

- Disconnected
- Connected

Those states are exposed through a state property in the connection but there are no states for anything else.

From the what anurse said in [this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1396) , the`start` Promise lets you know when the connection starts and the `closed` event lets you know it's stopped. They don't have automatic reconnects, so those are the only state transitions.

So you could use the following method as  Dennis1679 said above

```
connection.onclose(function(){
    console.log('connecition closed');
});
```